# Prove or disprove the following state $\lim_{m\to\infty}||A^m||=0$ then $\rho(A)\leq1$

Tags: calculus, analysis, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Prove or disprove the following state $\lim_{m\to\infty}||A^m||=0$ then $\rho(A)\leq1$,
I know that $\rho(A)\leq ||A||$ for every induced norm and my intution is that the statment is true but not sure how to prove it.
Any hints please?

Comment: Is A a matrix or a linear operator on an infinite dimensional space?

Comment: ||A|| is induced matrix norm

Comment: It is true that  $||A^m||\leq ||A||^m$. If in addition, A is self adjoint, then $ρ(Α)=||Α||$ and so the limit is zero. I am not sure about the case when A is not self adjoint

Comment: Have you heard of the [Gelfand's formula (a.k.a. spectral radius formula)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Gelfand's_formula)?

Comment: SangchulLee nope,
@EvangelopoulosF. All i can deduce is that the lim of $\lim||A||^m\geq 0$

Comment: Is your matrix self adjoint $(A=A^*)$ or normal $(AA^*=A^*A)$?

Comment: No,Just random matrix

Comment: Ah, I misread the question. Since the limit is zero, it must be true that $||A^m||$ is eventually less that one and thus $||A^m||^{1/m}$ is less than one. Now use the spectral radius formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an eigen value $\lambda$ with $|\lambda |>1$ the there is  vecor $x \neq 0$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$. This gives $A^{m}x=\lambda ^{m}x$. So $A^{m}y=\lambda ^{m}y$ where $y=\frac x {\|x\|}$ is a unit vector. Now $\|A^{m}\| \geq \|A^{m}y\|=|\lambda ^{m}| \to  \infty$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $c$ is a positive number, then there is $m_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that

$$||A^m|| \le c$$

for $m >m_0.$ Hence

$$||A^m||^{1/m} \le c^{1/m}$$

for $m >m_0.$ With $ m \to \infty$ we get

$$\rho(A) \le 1.$$

Remark: this holds for any bounded linear operator $A: V \to V$ on a normed linear space $V$.